# Getting error while building a project for android on unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in Unity, I'm trying to build android app using unity which has vr Support. I'm using Google VR and cardboard plugin.
I was initially able to build the project but after I made some changes in the scene its showing error in build.

1st error

DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/home/suhas/Unity Projects/ProjectRoom/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data'.
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (System.Int32 errorCode, System.String maybeFullPath) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].HandleError (System.Int32 hr, System.String path) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0) System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].CommonInit () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource]..ctor (System.String path, System.String originalUserPath, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.IO.SearchResultHandler`1[TSource] resultHandler, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.CreateFileNameIterator (System.String path, System.String originalUserPath, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean includeFiles, System.Boolean includeDirs, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames (System.String path, System.String userPathOriginal, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean includeFiles, System.Boolean includeDirs, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.SplitLargeFiles.SplitFiles (System.String path, System.String extension, System.Int32 threshold) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.SplitLargeFiles.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at :0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:337)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

2nd error

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002be] in /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

I've been stuck at this error from past two days. Please do help.
Thank you.

Comment: First thing I would do is quit Unity, make sure the `/home/suhas/Unity Projects/ProjectRoom/Temp` directory is gone, then try again. If that didn't work I'd quit Unity and `git clean -fdx` to remove everything that isn't committed and try again. If that didn't work I'd start moving back through commits until I found one that worked then diff against the head to see what had changed and figure out how to fix it. If you don't use source control you should start, but deleting the Library directory in the project is usually almost as good as cleaning everything.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am using source control. I tried to change to change different changeseat it worked.